# Development environment on device without administrator

Tags: development-environment

I am trying to do programming while I am in school on my school computer so I can do more time, but I always seem to run into the problem of needing admin to install things like a compiler or something like visual studio. Is there some way I could create an environment where I have control?

Answer (score 0):

Penguini! Yes, u can install VirtualBox or VMWare and download iso's with OS that you need to use! Or you can try to use a portable version of programs you like :)
Or just take ur notebook with you to school, if u have it